# Calvert curricular poem

Tags: poetry, identification-request

Many moons ago, I used the Calvert curriculum for something like 3rd-8th grade. I remember reading a poem about two brothers who had very different philosophies about how to accomplish their goals; each ended up ruining the other's work. I *believe* the last stanza went like this:

> Across the sea, the wide, wide sea
>   Two brothers are breaking their hearts.

I feel like there was another line where one brother laments

> "My blood, my sweat, my tears."

Does anybody remember the poem? I have not been able to find it online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The Two Brothers* by Isaac Leib Peretz, originally written in Yiddish. Mentioned as *“Di tsvey brider (fun fremdn khupe-kleyd)” (The two brothers, from “Strange Wedding Gown”)* on [Yiddish Leksikon](http://yleksikon.blogspot.com/2018/08/yitskhok-leybush-perets-isaac-leib.html).

Searching for ["My blood, my sweat, my tears! " "Over the sea"](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1252&bih=600&tbm=bks&ei=zIA4XODHKpCHwPAPrLaF2AY&q=%22My%20blood%2C%20my%20sweat%2C%20my%20tears%21%20%22%20%22Over%20the%20sea%22&oq=%22My%20blood%2C%20my%20sweat%2C%20my%20tears%21%20%22%20%22Over%20the%20sea%22) on Google books shows some fragments of it.

> On the other side of the wide blue sea
>   Stood a house that was simple and pretty and wee.
>   It hid in the valley, a humble cot
>   Of logs and clay in a hidden spot.
>   Each day the sun would flush with gold
>   A little window quaint and old.
>   And the moon would rise,
>   And its clear, pure eyes
>   Would paint the panes with silver.
>   And love was the blessing that Heaven sent
>   To the brothers who lived there in
>   content.

[...]

> And joy is dead, and sleep is done,
>   And love is away and forever gone.
>   One cries—“My wealth, my dream of years!”
>   The other—“My blood, my sweat, my tears!”
>   Over the sea,
>   The wide blue sea,
>   Two brothers are breaking their hearts.

Details added based on the investigative work mentioned in the comments.

Comment: It's a poem by **Isaac Leib Peretz** originally written in Yiddish. (The [second result](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=d81RAQAAMAAJ&q=%22My+blood,+my+sweat,+my+tears!+%22+%22Over+the+sea%22) on your Google books link shows the poem "translated by Jacob Robbins", and [searching for that in turn](https://www.google.com/search?ei=NYg4XOr9BZH5wQKk0wg&q=%22translated+by+jacob+robbins%22+%22the+two+brothers%22) gives a [404 page](http://library.kilgore.edu/vufind/Record/205752/TOC) whose Google preview [is helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUGEh.png).

Comment: It's also mentioned on [this page](http://yleksikon.blogspot.com/2018/08/yitskhok-leybush-perets-isaac-leib.html) as “Di tsvey brider (fun fremdn khupe-kleyd)” (The two brothers, from “Strange Wedding Gown”).

Comment: Thanks so much! My Google-fu was foiled, but I bow before the masters.